# What is the status of locally integrated menus for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, menu, appmenu, locally-integrated-menus

How can I know the current development status of LIM (locally integrated menus). 
Can I install LIM in Precise Beta 2?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIM has been dropped for 12.04. It probably is on the blueprint for 12.10. There was a PPA which included packages for LIM but it is not active for a while. You can find the PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~unity-team/+archive/lim).

You can read more about the development focus of LIM in the [OMG!Ubuntu! article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/lim-feature-explained-may-land-in-12-04-update/).